# The type org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver is not accessible

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I got an error The type org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver is not accessible after uplaoding JArS files of selenium webdriver usinf eclipse IDE & JAVA . I need your help please ?

```
package samplePackage;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class WebDriverDemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver;

    }

}
```

Comment: In Eclipse click Project / Clean. If you have disabled autobuild, than moreover Project / Build project.

Answer (score 2):

Delete the **module.java** or **module.info.java** from your project

Answer (score 1):

If it has not already worked after what @pburgr has said, then make sure you have added the right JAR e.g. `selenium-java-3.14.0.jar`

If you have written `import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;` yourself then remove it, write `WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();` and then let eclipse import the correct classes itself. Or you can do Cmd+Shift+O and it will import the right classes automatically.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution : delete the module.java from your project